# Добавить значение в QuerySet, ручками

Tags: python, queryset, django

Нужно добавить значения в QuerySet модели UserQueAns. Значения id_que = 1, id_ans = 2, user_id = 252. Значения я получил с формы ручками после валидации их обрабатываю, но засунуть в таблицу UserQueAns в ручную не выходит, ругается что нужно только по ключам из связанных таблиц добавлять.

Как добавить нужные мне цифры в эту таблицу?

Вот модели:

```
class UserQuestion(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(_(u'Вопрос'), max_length = 200,  blank = False)
    show_question = models.BooleanField(_(u'Показывать вопрос'), default = False)
    class Meta:
        app_label = "profile"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question

class UserAnswerQue(models.Model):
    id_que = models.ForeignKey(UserQuestion, null = True, blank = True, verbose_name = _(u'Вопрос'))
    answer = models.CharField(_(u'Ответ'), max_length = 200, blank = True)
    show_answer = models.BooleanField(_(u'Показывать ответ'), default = False)
    class Meta:
        app_label = "profile"

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.answer

class UserQueAns(models.Model):
    id_que = models.ForeignKey(UserQuestion, null = True, blank = False, verbose_name = _(u'Вопрос'))
    id_ans = models.ForeignKey(UserAnswerQue, null = True, blank = True, verbose_name = _(u'Ответ'))
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, null = True, blank = False, verbose_name = _(u'Пользователь'))
    class Meta:
        app_label = "profile"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
id_que = 1
id_ans = 2
user_id = 252
userQueAns = UserQueAns(
    id_que = UserQuestion.objects.get(id = id_que),
    id_ans = UserAnswerQue.objects.get(id = id_ans),
    user_id = User.objects.get(id = user_id)
    )
userQuetAns.save()
```

**ПС лучше поменять модель вот так**

```
class UserQueAns(models.Model):
    que = models.ForeignKey(UserQuestion, null = True, blank = False, verbose_name = _(u'Вопрос'))
    ans = models.ForeignKey(UserAnswerQue, null = True, blank = True, verbose_name = _(u'Ответ'))
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null = True, blank = False, verbose_name = _(u'Пользователь'))
```

В бд ваши поля будут называться id_que_id и id_ans_id , а эти более красиво. Или укажите через атрибут db_column = "название поля" то называние которое хотите.

Comment: Отлично, всё сработало. Спасибо. За названия уже понял, когда по модели сгенерились таблицы. Но спасибо за советы, если буду удалять и перегенерить, то обязательно исправлю ошибки.